# Get git tags and commit messages from remote server

Tags: python, git, gerrit

I have the following problem: 
Versioning in the projects I'm handling is done through tags. I want to generate version information from all commits between two tags.

- The commits messages contain an reference number (for example MT1234 or HX1234 and a couple of other types) which I want to get.
- What I want is `git log --pretty=oneline tag1...tag2` but *remotely* *without* *cloning*.
- I got access through git repos and also through Gerrit.

---

- I solved the problem by making a script that clones all repos, and extracts information from the cloned repo. However, its many many repos I need to go through, and the repos are big. If this is going to be used for a foreseeable future I need stop cloning.
- I've tried using `git archive` single folders/files, but it does not copy the `.git` folder. Unless of course, you know a way to get a file from the .git folder.
- I've tried Gerrit API, but cannot figure out how I am supposed to get all commits between two tags as `git log --pretty=oneline tag1...tag2`.
- I think I can search Gerrit for all merged commits, match them with tags/commits from `git ls-remote` and try find intermediate commits by looking at the timestamp. It might work, but I'm afraid that I miss something.

---

Do you have any suggestions on how to get the equivalent information of `git log --pretty=oneline tag1...tag2` remotely without cloning, with git and Gerrit available?

Comment: Build a server that runs on the machine that *does* have the Git repositories, that does the `git log` command you want done. Call that server, have it run the command, take its output.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SSH access to the Gerrit server? You could execute something like this:

```
ssh USER@GERRIT-SERVER git --git-dir=GERRIT-SITE/git/REPO-PATH-NAME log --pretty=oneline TAG1..TAG2
```

Comment: Good idea, but I'm not sure. I will see if I can.